# QObject auto-delete

Tags: qt, qt4, qevent

I am having some problems with a QObject that is being deleted when I don't expect it to.

I have this class (note that I don't declare Q_OBJECT)

```
class MyEntry : public QTreeWidgetItem
{
public:
    MyEntry(QTreeWidgetItem* _parent, QString _name = "noname") :
      QTreeWidgetItem(_parent, QStringList() << _name) {}

    ... it holds a few QStrings and has some setter/getter methods for them
};
```

I create and use this object in a class that contains a QTreeWidget. Every now and then this class "sends" one of its MyEntries to a different class which uses the info from the MyEntry it is being sent to set the text on some QLabels it holds. I use the following QEvent:

```
class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    MyEvent(MyEntry* _ob) : QEvent((QEvent::Type)MYEVENT1), mp_ob(_ob) {}
    ~MyEvent() {}
    MyEntry* getOb() { return mp_ob; }
private:
    MyEntry* mp_ob;
};
```

I send and receive this event like so (the receiver is parent() and lp_currentEntry is a MyEntry object):

```
Class that contains the QTreeWidget:

QApplication::postEvent(parent() , new MyEvent(lp_currentEntry));


Class that contains the QLabels:

void MyOtherClass::customEvent(QEvent* _p_ev)
{
  return;
}
```

The problem I have is that as soon as the event has been delivered, the MyEvent is being deleted. But the destructor of the MyEntry it contains is also called. I never created the MyEntry using the MyEvent as a parent so why is it being deleted?

I am using this setup because the postEvent is usually done by a thread which is not the ui one and I am pretty sure non-ui threads shouldn't update QLabels etc, otherwise I could have simply done `(MyOtherClass*)parent()->updateLabels(lp_currentEntry);` - but correct me there if I am wrong.

**Edit**: Here is a backtrace:

```
#0  MyEntry::~MyEntry (this=0x7f83a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../jb2/containers.cpp:171
#1  0x000000000040ede9 in MyEntry::~MyEntry (this=0x7f83a0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../jb2/containers.cpp:178
#2  0x0000000000416439 in ~MyEvent (this=0xfc7810, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../jb2/jb2Events.h:28
#3  MyEvent::~MyEvent (this=0xfc7810, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../jb2/jb2Events.h:28
#4  0x0000003ad317b45a in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x0000003ad31a5e33 in ?? () from /lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#6  0x0000003b24847825 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x0000003b24847b58 in ?? () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#8  0x0000003b24847c14 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0
#9  0x0000003ad31a5fc6 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#10 0x0000003ad4a6a5ee in ?? () from /lib64/libQtGui.so.4
#11 0x0000003ad31766ef in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#12 0x0000003ad3176978 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#13 0x0000003ad317b768 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib64/libQtCore.so.4
#14 0x0000000000408f53 in main (argc=1, argv=<optimized out>) at ../jb2/main.cpp:10
```

Comment: I don't know why your object's getting deleted (have you tried putting a breakpoint on the destructor?) but QTreeWidgetItem is not a QObject.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I do this: QApplication::postEvent(parent() , new MyEvent(0)); everything works fine .. I don't get a segmentation fault when it tries to delete a null pointer either so obviously it isn't trying to do that

Comment: Calling delete on a null pointer is perfectly legal in C++, but certainly your MyEntry should not be getting deleted by the MyEvent if your sample code is accurate.  I think you need to get a stack trace of where the deletion occurs before anyone will be able to assist you further.

Comment: I added the backtrace .. ~MyEntry is called from ~MyEvent. Not sure what the "optimized out" messages mean.

Comment: Is thera any chance that you called clear() on your QTreeWidget before your event was delivered by postEvent?